# Converting direct speech to indirect speech

Tags: idioms, punctuation, indirect-speech, narration

Please tell me what will be the indirect-speech form of this sentence:

> The boys shouted, "Don Bosco Public School well played?"

The question mark confuses me.

Here is the original question:
   
[image]
with options:                <sub>(manually transcribed)</sub>

- (a) The boys     asked    for Don Bosco Public School well played.
- (b) The boys     applauded    Don Bosco Public School
  saying that it had                                      played well.
- (c) The boys     cried    for Don Bosco Public School well played.
- (d) The boys     cheered  for Don Bosco Public School well played.

Comment: Do you mean "Don boscho school played well?"

Comment: @Nick *Well played* is an idiomatic compliment that a particular maneuver was executed with skill.

Comment: The current sentence isnt grammatical though - switching those two words would make it so.

Comment: The question mark is confusing you because *"Don Boscho School well played?"* is completely unidiomatic for any dialect of English I know of. I suspect it's a typo and should be an exclamation point.

Comment: @Peter Shor: ok

Answer (score 1):

I've assumed that the question mark is a typo and intended to be an exclamation point, as other commenters suggest. "*Well played!*" would be the boys shouting that the Don Bosco Public School played well. In indirect speech something like

> The boys shouted that Don Bosco Public School had played well

would convey a similar meaning. In the image you linked, answer **b** is your closest option to this.

Comment: Absolutely, that is the correct way to write the sentence as reported speech. None of the choices in the picture is right.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the correct grammatical reading would be,
"Don Bosco School, well played!"

If so, the *indirect* speech would be an assumed subject in the second clause. The Deep Structure of the sentence would read something like this:
"Don Bosco School, [that particular move, or that series of moves, was] well played."

I think that's what you mean. If you're looking for an indirect object here, I can't find it.

Comment: No, the question was about indirect speech, not indirect objects.  Direct speech is a quote: *The boys shouted, "Don Boscho School plays well!"* Indirect speech is a report of the quote: *The boys shouted that Don Boscho School played well.* (I backshifted *play* to past tense but that isn't required.) The problem is that the original quote doesn't contain a finite verb, and the relative clause of indirect speech requires one.

Comment: @deadrat - Why did you keep the comma between 'shouted' and the quote?  Isn't the quoted speech the direct object of 'shouted'?

Comment: @AmI Comma-quote is the standard way to represent direct speech.  I'm not sure that quoted speech fits into the direct object slot the way *instructions* would in *He shouted **instructions***.

Comment: Thanks; the comma seems redundant... You say, "goodbye", and I say "hello."